# Find the sub determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

If I have the matrix $A(x)$ which is $5 x 5$ and I need to find the $t x t$ sub-determinants of $A(x)$ for $t = 1$ to $t = 5$, how do I do this? $A(x)$ =  \begin{pmatrix} 
(x-1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & (x-1) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & (x-1) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (x+1) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (x+1) 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: That's quite a lot of sub-determinants... Even though many of them will be $0$.

Comment: @julien yes, it is, I just need to know how to find them.  I need them to find the smith canonical matrix equivalent to the matrix above. I thought I was doing it correctly, but it turns out, I am getting different answers from the solution set I have.  :(

Comment: For $t=1$, you get a lot of $0$'s, 3 times $x-1$, twice $x+1$, and $-1$. So the gcd is $1$. Now for $t=2$, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look for the Smith Canonical Form, since it is your goal behind the question.

For $t=1$, we get in particular $x-1$ and $x+1$, whose $gcd$ is $1$, so the gcd of all $1\times 1$ minors is $1$.

For $t=2$, we get in particular $(x-1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$, whose $gcd$ is $1$, so the gcd of all $2\times 2$ minors is $1$.

For $t=3$, the only nonzero $3\times 3$ minors are $(x-1)^3, (x-1)^2(x+1), (x-1)(x+1)^2$. So the gcd is $(x-1)(x+1)$.

For $t=4$, the only nonzero $4\times 4$ minors are $(x-1)^3(x+1), (x-1)^2(x+1)^2$. So the gcd is $(x-1)^2(x+1)$.

For $t=5$, the determinant is $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$.

So the Smith Canonical should be the diagonal matrix 
$$
\mbox{diag}(1,1,(x-1)(x+1), x-1, (x-1)(x+1)).
$$

Comment: could you refer a site that will show me how to determine subdeterminants? I have another matrix I am working with and again, I am getting the wrong the subdeterminant for $t_3$ wrong.  Many thanks :) sarah

Comment: @sarahjamal Sorry, I don't know such a reference. For instance, for a $3\times 3$ subdeterminant of $5\times 5$ matrix $A$, you need to take $3$ indices $1\leq i_1<i_2<i_3\leq 5$ and then compute the determinant of the $3\times 3$ submatrix matrix $(a_{i_n,i_m})$. For all of them, you need to consider all choices of such $3$ indices. Does that help?